# Neo4j and Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, cypher

I have a complex analytical Neo4j Cypher query which I run each time in run-time. According to the following documentation, https://neo4j.com/developer/apache-spark/ looks like I may execute the query on Apache Spark cluster:

```
org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j(sc).cypher("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n.name").partitions(5).batch(10000).loadRowRdd
```

Does this mean that instead of doing such a simple query, I can do a Cypher query of any complexity this way to take advantage of Spark's in-memory parallel processing?

Comment: The page you are linking states: This page is deprecated in favor of the Neo4j Connector for Apache Spark

Comment: But probably, you can use a Cypher query to fetch data from neo4j to spark... not that spark would somehow magically improve the performance of cypher queries

Comment: I'm interested in the Spark parallelism. Will Spark connector just take the query and execute it as is.. or will it be separated internally on set of paginated queries for instance? For what purpose `.partitions(5).batch(10000).` is specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the new Neo4j Spark Connector states:

> partitions: This defines the parallelization level while pulling data
> from Neo4j. Note: as more parallelization does not mean better query
> performance, tune wisely in according to your Neo4j installation.

You can definitely try it out, but it isn't a given that the performance will be better. Read more in the docs: https://neo4j.com/docs/spark/current/reading/